# Get Unix path from Mounted drive in batch

Tags: windows, unix, path, mount

Just wanted to pass this along because it took me a couple days to figure this out. I'm not a batch guy, more of a unix guy but what I have is a build.bat that is run from a mounted unix drive and runs build scripts on Windows and Unix from a windows cmd prompt. I use to have the paths hardcoded in the bat file but I wanted to be able to put the scripts anywhere on Unix and allow a user to checkout the source to their own sandbox, mount the drive open cmd prompt, cd to scripts dir and just run the build. There are many processes run from this script. So I had to derive the path from the mounted drive. Again - I'm sure there maybe and easier or shorter way but this works for me:

```
@echo off

set USERNAME=%1
set PASSWORD=%2

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: All scripts are run from the same script directory on the mounted unix drive
:: 
:: Get the unix path to the scripts directory by using the following command
::
::    net use %~d0
:: 
:: %~d0  - drive letter where the script is running from
:: %~dp0 - complete path to this script
::
set WIN_PATH=%~dp0
set DRIVE_LETTER=%~d0

:: get "Remote Name" from net use command
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('net use %DRIVE_LETTER% ^| FINDSTR /I "^Remote"') DO SET NET_USE_OUTPUT=%%i

:: Get mounted unix drive from net use drive_letter, returns //ServerName/mount
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ("%NET_USE_OUTPUT%") DO SET MOUNTED_DRIVE=%%A

::  substitute drive_Letter for mounted_drive \\serverName\mount\path\to\scripts 
set WIN_MOUNTED_PATH=!WIN_PATH:%DRIVE_LETTER%=%MOUNTED_DRIVE%!

::  Change to win to Unix slashes //serverName/mount/path/to/scripts
set UNX_MOUNTED_PATH=%WIN_MOUNTED_PATH:\=/%

:: get SERVER_NAME 
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=/" %%A IN ("%UNX_MOUNTED_PATH%") DO SET "SERVER_NAME=%%A"

:: Remove //serverName from full path - not needed on unix server
SET "SERVER_NAME_REMOVE=*//%SERVER_NAME%"

:: Remove serverName to get unix path to scripts directory
::  SCRIPTS = /path/to/scripts
CALL SET SCRIPTS=%%UNX_MOUNTED_PATH:!SERVER_NAME_REMOVE!=%%

:: Run script on Unix using plink
pink -pw %PASSWORD% %USERNAME%@%SERVER_NAME% "%SCRIPTS%/run.sh"

:: Run script on Windows
%WIN_PATH%run.bat
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's fine to ask a question and then answer it yourself, but you should probably edit this post down to just the question part, then post your answer below.